# How to disable camera on iOS devices in specific locations using a configuration profile or app

Tags: ios, camera, geolocation, configuration-profiles

What I need to do is to disable the iOS camera (and any apps using the camera, of course) when entering a specific location. I know that I can use a configuration profile that disables the camera completely, but that's unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html), it is not possible to restrict functionality based on geolocation. As you note you can disable the camera entirely, but that is the only current option.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that the config profile probably doesn't allow it. However, there might be an API that an app can use to disable the camera. Again, I'm just fishing -- I wasn't able to find any information on that either.

Comment: Unless you talking about a jailbroken phone, what one app does cannot affect the entire system. If an app were able to disable the camera, it would only disable it while _in that app_.